# How to fix HTML-<ul> list displaying long list items in flutter?

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I have an html view in my flutter app (with the package flutter_html: ^0.9.6).

Unfortunatly it breaks the lines right after the bullet points IF the content of the list item is longer than 1 line.

[here you see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5On1n.png)

How can I make the list item NOT breaking right after the bullet point?

I tryed to set it to `<ul style='display: block;'>` with no effect. Same with `<li style='display: block;'>`

This code creates the list:

```
String list = "<ul>";      
list = list + "<li>this is text for one line</li>\n";
list = list + "<li>this is where the problem comes because the 
text is longer than one line and there is a break
after the bullet</li>\n";
list = "$list </ul>";
```

I expected:

```
- this is text for one line
- this is where the problem comes because the 
  text is longer than one line and there is a break
  after the bullet
```

But I get:

```
- this is text for one line
-
this is where the problem comes because the 
text is longer than one line and there is a break
after the bullet
```

Answer (score 2):

Now it is supported in the new version of flutter_html upgrade your dependency to flutter_html: ^0.10.4